Bash dialog: how do I chain widgets, passing data from one to the next?
I'm trying to build a simple dialog where the user is asked to make a choice (with a menu widget) and then confirm it (with a yesno widget). The separate confirmation is required (preferred, anyway) because any following actions format your disk, which could lead to complaints.
Chaining widgets is easy enough, but passing selections from a menu to downstream widgets is non-trivial. Can anyone suggest a way to do this? In this attempt, the menu output goes to fd 3 (--output-fd won't take a pipe name), and I attempt to read fd 3 for the second widget:
#!/bin/bash

exec 3<> /tmp/fubar
confirm=$(cat /dev/fd/3 &)

res=$(dialog --clear \
       --output-fd 3 \
       --backtitle "Backtitle"  \
       --title "Title" \
       --menu "Please select:" 15 30 4 \
       "1" "Foo" \
       "2" "Bar" \
       --clear   \
       --stderr  \
       --yesno "$confirm" 15 30 \
       2>&1 >/dev/tty)

This doesn't work, of course, not least because $confirm is expanded early. I also need to build a confirmation string instead of just displaying an integer in the yesno box. Any ideas?
EDIT
Minor variation of Gilles' answer below, to use a var instead of a file:
#!/bin/bash

choice=$(dialog --clear \
    --backtitle "Backtitle" \
    --title "Title" \
    --menu "Please select:" 15 30 4 \
    "1" "Foo" \
    "2" "Bar" \
    2>&1 >/dev/tty)

case $choice in
    1) label="foo" ;;
    2) label="bar"  ;;
    *) echo >&2 "ERR $choice"; exit 1 ;;
esac

dialog --clear \
    --backtitle "Backtitle" \
    --title "Confirm" \
    --yesno "You selected option $label. Do you want to proceed?" 10 40


Your variation is less readable, less maintenable and you introduced a bug ¹. That was all the point to keep the things simple as in my answer.¹ 2>&1 is after file, and better use & shortcut: &>file in bash.

@GillesQuénot:  dialog outputs to stderr; curses outputs to stdout. This invocation allows the dialog output to be returned by $(), while keeping the curses output on /dev/tty. This is pretty much the canonical way to use dialog while avoiding temporary files.

Keep it simple stupid!
#!/bin/bash

trap 'rm -f /tmp/$$_temp' EXIT

dialog --clear \
    --output-fd 1 \
    --backtitle "Backtitle" \
    --title "Title" \
    --menu "Please select:" 15 30 4 \
    "1" "Foo" \
    "2" "Bar" >/tmp/$$_temp

case $(< /tmp/$$_temp) in
    1) label=yes ;;
    2) label=no  ;;
    *) echo >&2 "ERR $choice"; exit 1 ;;
esac

dialog --clear \
    --backtitle "Backtitle" \
    --title "Confirm" \
    --yesno "You selected option $label. Do you want to proceed?" 10 40
[...]


Wow. Do you think that's the only way to do it? I wouldn't be surprised.

Anything wrong with this solution?

Actually, it's alright. I've tried it and the change between the two dialog windows is seamless, so it looks good. I'll edit the question to post a slight variation on your solution to use a variable instead of a file. I'll accept if no-one else comes up with a magic built-in solution... :)

Usually, posting a new question better fit the guidelines on SO. Don't change question when you get an answer.

It's not part of the question: it's just a long comment which shows your solution with the canonical way to get results back from dialog. I'll remove it if you want to add it yourself.

I will not change anything. You are free to adapt to your needs, this is even recommended.

@GillesQuénot already answered your question so please do not accept this instead as this is not a different answer just a suggestion that's too long and formatted for a comment of a way to implement the existing solution without redundancy:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

prompt() {
    dialog \
        --clear \
        --backtitle 'Backtitle' \
        "$@" \
        2>&1 >/dev/tty
}

declare -A labels=(
    ['1']='Foo'
    ['2']='Bar'
)

titleArgs=(
    --title 'Title'
    --menu 'Please select:' 15 30 4
)

while IFS= read -r idx; do
    titleArgs+=( "$idx" "${labels[$idx]}" )
done < <(printf '%s\n' "${!labels[@]}" | sort -n)

choice=$( prompt "${titleArgs[@]}" )

if [[ -v labels["$choice"] ]]; then
    label="${labels[$choice]}"
else
    printf 'ERR %s\n' "$choice" >&2
    exit 1
fi

confirmArgs=(
    --title 'Confirm'
    --yesno "You selected option $choice ($label). Do you want to proceed?" 10 40
)

prompt "${confirmArgs[@]}"; confirmed=$?

printf 'confirmation result: %s\n' "$confirmed" >&2


Why [[ -v labels["$choice"] ]] instead of  [[ -v ${labels["$choice"]} ]] ?

@GillesQuénot bash magic. Sorry, I don't know the details of why that's the "does this index exist in an array" syntax. There are some things in bash that I just accept and move on... :-).
